# Strip function is not working as expected

Tags: python

```
def sstrip(a):

    b=raw_input("enter the string to be stripped off")
    i=a.strip(b)
    print i

k=raw_input("enter the string")

sstrip(k)
```

---

output:

```
enter the string - is it available?

enter the string to be stripped off - is

t available?
```

In the above program i is part of two string is and it.."it" is a mid word.In that also i getting stripped off.

Could someone help me

Comment: What do you think `a.strip(b)` does ? Should `a` be involved in the strip action ? ;)

Comment: If it's not as expected, read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)

Comment: I think OP's difficulty is that strip() is the only place I can think of offhand where a set of characters is specified as a string. And he is clearly not alone, because the 2.7.13 documentation says "The chars argument is not a prefix or suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped". That bit was added recently.

Answer (score 1):

`str.strip` strips by character (keeps removing until a character not in the parameter is reached), and the problem is that you're including a whitespaces before `is` in your input:

```
>>> 'is it'.strip('is')
' it'
>>> 'is it'.strip('- is')
't'
```

If what you actually want to do is *slice* off the substring from the start or end of the larger string, then you can use the following:

```
def rcut(a, b):
    return a[:-len(b)] if a.endswith(b) else a

def cut(a, b):
    a = rcut(a, b)
    return a[len(b):] if a.startswith(b) else a

print cut('- is it available?', '- is')
# it available?
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by this prompt in your program

```
b=raw_input("enter the string to be stripped off")
```

you expect that `strip()` strips off substring prefixes and suffixes. It doesn't. `strip()` removes unwanted *characters*.

If you want to remove one instance of substring `b` from anywhere in string `a`:

```
pieces = a.partition(b)
i = pieces[0] + pieces[2]
```

If, on the other hand, you want to remove only prefixes and suffixes, like `strip()` does:

```
i = a
if i.startswith(b):
    i = i[len(b):]
if i.endswith(b):
    i = i[:len(b)]
```

And if you want to remove *multiple occurrences* of the same prefix or suffix substring, again like `strip()` does, then substitute `while` for `if`.

Comment: Thanks for kind response..useful one